# Is there a way to send a specific message to a specific server and channel on discord with python?

Tags: python, discord

I just need to send a message that says "!daily" in a server called 'bot-commands' every 86401 seconds (24 hours and 1 second)

Any tips please

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to do a command with another bot, most bots make it so other ones can't do commands, so it probably won't work, but you can make a `before_loop`:

```
import asyncio
import datetime as dt


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Logged in as")
    print(bot.user.name)
    print("------")
    msg1.start()


# Message 1
@tasks.loop(hours=24)
async def msg1():
    message_channel = bot.get_channel(705524214270132367)
    await message_channel.send("test 1")


@msg1.before_loop
async def before_msg1():
    for _ in range(60*60*24):  # loop the hole day
        if dt.datetime.now().hour == 10+12:  # 24 hour format
            print('It is time')
            return
        await asyncio.sleep(1)# wait a second before looping again. You can make it more
```

Another option is using a workflow website such as IFTTT or Zapier.

Comment: Is that for python 3.9.1 64 bit because it won't even let me do the second line

Comment: @KianJohnFleming thats because its an import and you have to do pip install DateTime first

Comment: do I install Datetime-4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl or Datetime-4.3.tar.gz

Comment: @KianJohnFleming
Can you show me your code on how you got to that?

Comment: I'm just on pypi.org/project/DateTime/#files and there's 2 options to download

Comment: Thats not how you install it. Go to your terminal and type 'pip install DateTime'

Comment: I managed to download it and it's gave me a warning that says "You are using pip version 20.2.3 however version 21.0.1 is available" and "you should consider upgrading via the 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe -m pip install-- upgrade pip command

Comment: @NuggetaofWisdom I don't think it did, I wrote everything exactly as you did above, but when it came to 'async Def before_msg1(): it kept saying syntaxes error

Comment: @KianJohnFleming Did you change the channel id?

Comment: i didn't know there were pieces you had to change... are they the parts you put in quotes? Or with dashes?